# In The Flashpoint Paradox, if Flash stopped his earlier self from changing past then how is a new timeline created?

Tags: dc, flashpoint-paradox, dc-animated-movie-universe, flashpoint

The New 52 version of DC, which is caused by the events of the *Flashpoint* story, it is also shown in movie *Justice League: The Flashpoint Paradox*.

But how is a new timeline created at the end of the movie if the Flash stopped his earlier self from changing the past?

Answer (score 1):

Everytime Flash does a time jump,he creates an alternative timeline. The original timeline stays put as it is even if the past is changed...

You can better take it as the burning of a matchstick. You can go back and stop yourself from doing that but in the present time, it has already burnt and therefore you create an alternate reality instead...

Now,since time traveling is not an exact science and is mostly discussed in comics, you should watch the 11th episode of CW's The Flash S02, in which the Reverse Flash aka Eobard Thawne returns to their timeline,however being erased from existence in the 1st Season Finale where Eddie Thawne kills himself...

It is a time remnant thing and also a sort of time paradox!

Comment: @VaibhavPuri Did you not find my answer satisfactory? Is their something more you need?

Comment: “since time traveling is not an exact science” — *[citation needed]*.